# Don't rollback the transaction on error in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions

When an error occurs in an Entity Framework operation, any ambient transaction is aborted and I can't use it for more database work. As soon as I try to open a nested transaction scope, for example, it throws a `TransactionAbortedException` saying "The transaction has aborted."

What can I do to prevent that when I expect errors and know how to continue?

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var x = ctx.MyEntities.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch
        {
            CreateTable();
            // Custom DDL command. I can't use EF migrations.
            // Should that fail or not help, I'm happy to see more exceptions later.
        }
        // TODO: Transaction scope is already aborted!
        ctx.MyEntities.Add(...);
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

I could make a new `DbContext` instance if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not document what kinds of exceptions roll back the transaction. You can't make it not roll back which frankly is stupid and there is no technical reason for it. It also is prone to simply continue executing in case of error (then without a transaction). Also, it is quite unpredictable what kinds of errors roll back and which ones do not.

The transaction is not being rolled back by EF. SQL Server does that.

You probably can execute raw SQL with exception handling:

```
TRY
 YourStatementHere
END TRY
CATCH
...
```

This *should* keep the transaction alive.

Comment: I'm in Entity Framework, using mapped queries. Additionally, this is supposed to work with multiple databases. (I was in fact testing with SQL Server first, but I did not mention it.) Heavily customised SQL is not an option here. And errors of the kind "Table does not exist" are expected in this scenario, hence the `CreateTable` call as a measure to handle the error. +1 for the info that the database server already aborts the transaction, not EF.

Comment: Then you are out of luck... Maybe you can start a different connection+transaction pair and do the check there. Your main tran will live.

Comment: That's it, another `TransactionScope` with the option `Suppress` did the trick. I needed to take the potentially failing command out of the transaction. Since it may return outdated data, I have to repeat it within the transaction if there was no error and use that result.

Comment: OK. Another warning: EF opens a new connection for each query. This causes escalation to MSDTC. Disable MSDTC on your machine to catch such problems.

Comment: I haven't observed any problems related to distributed transactions, also with MSDTC service stopped. Just using a single database. Also, regarding SQL Server, this should have been fixed 7 years ago with SQL Server 2008, from what I've read.

Comment: Not sure what fix you mean. MSDTC escalation might not happen even if you are using multiple connections if you happen to take the same physical connection from the pool twice. This is insidious. Usually, during test you won't notice. In production under load it can happen.